# How to Install Selenium - Java in VScode for Linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: java, selenium, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, selenium-chromedriver

I have some great difficulty in finding a way to install and run Selenium with VS code in Ubuntu. All the other tutorials I found on the Internet where for Eclipse. And those with VS Code where in either python or C#.

Comment: What is your question? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Or, is this supposed to be an _answer_ to your own question? If so, ask the question as a question (and provide details about what the _specific_ problem is that you faced). But then, provide the answer _as an answer_ (not in the question), using the blue "Post Your Answer" button.

Comment: it is the answer. I will just add it to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download and install VScode from Ubuntu Software Store or Download directly from https://code.visualstudio.com/download and open using package installer.

[image]

2. Update ubuntu softwares in terminal.

   `sudo apt update`
3. **Installing Java jdk**

   If java jdk is not installed, then install with following command :

   `sudo apt install default-jdk`

   It will add the path automatically.
4. Download the Selenium Client & Web Driver for Java from https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

[image]

5. Install Google Chrome from here. Select the correct version of your Linux and Download. Open with Sofware installer to install chrome.

https://www.google.com/chrome/

[image]

6. **Installing Chrome Driver and moving it to root**

Open Terminal and type these commands one after the other.

```
 wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/chromedriver_linux64.zip
 unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
 sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
 sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/chromedriver
 sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

7. **Open a new Java Project Folder**

   To open a new Java project :

   • Open Visual Studio Code

   • Shortcut Ctrl+Shift+P or Click on Run a Command

   • Enter Create Java Project

   • Click No build Tools.

   • Choose a location for the folder and Name the project

[image]

8. **Adding libraries Into java project folder**

There will be a hello world program already present – App.java

[image]

In the **explorer menu** there is tab called **Java Projects** – extend the tab.       There is a Tab named “**Referenced Libraries**” . Click the “**+**” next to it.
Add the .jar files from the Selenium-java zip folder(Selenium Client & Web Driver for java we had downloaded earlier ) after extracting it.
There are 2 in the main folder and 5 inside the libs folder. Add all of them to “**Referenced Libraries**”.

Here is the ss of the files after adding them all.

[image]

9. **Running Demo program to check**

Add the following code to App.java

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://www.google.com");
driver.quit(); 
}
}
```

Now for running the code you might need to intall the **java extention package** in VS code **Extentions**.
After that install an extention named **Code Runner**.
This will let you run the code by clicking on run without any errors. Look at run Java button on top right corner. That is the button for running java code.

The above program will open Google chrome with google.com and close it once it completes loading.

[image]

Comment: this is masterpiece! i searched on youtube on how to set this up on vscode but none of them ggave me clear explanation. thank you!